# CMake module for gettext support?

Tags: localization, cmake, gettext, xgettext

Is there a good, open-source, documented CMake module for gettext support?

I mean:

- Extracting messages from sources
- Merging messages to existing translations
- Compilation of mo-files
- Installation of mo-files.

Because plain macros that CMake provides are quite... useless for real l10n support.

*Anybody?*

**Edit:** I created my own cmake rules for my own project but I don't think that
it is long term solution especially when you have multiple projects.

So it would be really helpful if someone directed me to such module.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to write a gettext module for another project. So I made it user friendly and uploaded it to git hub.

https://github.com/jarro2783/CMake-Gettext

Answer (score 1):

Wesnoth has their own solution.

See the code:
[svn.gna.org/viewcvs/wesnoth/trunk/po/CMakeLists.txt?rev=42032&view=markup](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/wesnoth/trunk/po/CMakeLists.txt?rev=42032&view=markup)

And for reference:
[svn.gna.org/viewcvs/wesnoth/trunk/CMakeLists.txt?rev=42920&view=markup](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/wesnoth/trunk/CMakeLists.txt?rev=42920&view=markup)

I’m not too sure this is really ”good” solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

So late 2011 I started work on a CMake module:

https://github.com/Jookia/GettextTools

It fulfils everything you require.